# Facebook's auth.promoteSession deprecated - alternatives?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been contacted by Facebook noting that the auth.promoteSession REST API is being deprecated on January 7th. My application uses this to generate a session token from our permanent access token so we can pass it along to the user's browser as a cookie.

We need this to allow the Facebook JavaScript API to be used without making the user login twice.

Has anyone come across an alternative to this API call?

Comment: I really think that facebook should put more effort on their documentations...anyway try keeping this [post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=84151) up and you might get an answer from a FB developer or something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are holding off on deprecating this method until they have an alternative.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/issue/198